# Get number of characters matched in regex

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3

I have a file indented with a single space indentation:

```
Level1 with some text
 Level2 
Level1 
  Level3 and its text
```

I want to indent it with 4 spaces. I thought about a regex to match starting space `^(\s)*`. However, I don't know how to replace it with "apply one tab for each space found".

My expected output would be:

```
Level1 with some text
    Level2 
Level1 
        Level3 and its text
```

Does something like `\t*len(\1)` exist?

**edit:** I would appreciate a Regex based solution because I aim to use it from within SublimeText editor which has a replace functionnality by regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the Python regex engine supports this, but since you mentioned using Sublime Text, you can use the [`\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html), which matches the position immediately after the end of the previous match.

```
Find What:     (^|\G)\s
Replace With:  \t
```

This pattern will match any single whitespace character which immediately follows the start of the line *or* the previous match.

Comment: Interresting! I did not know the `\G` anchor. Indeed, in my use case it will work perfectly!

Comment: +1 but it's a little known fact that `\G` matches at the beginning of the string, so you can simplify the regex. Quite annoying in fact, see for instance [this demo](http://ideone.com/zla7zk)—same in Sublime. I often have to use things like `(?:(?!^)\G)`

Answer (score 2):

I think regex might be overkill for this problem.  Why not try something like this (assuming your original text file is called `test.txt`),

```
#new_space = '\t'
new_space = '    '
f = open( 'new.txt', 'w' )
for line in open( 'test.txt', 'r' ):
    nw = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
    if nw != 0:
        f.write( nw*new_space + line.lstrip() )
    else:
        f.write( line ) 
f.close()
```

Comment: I edited my answer, performance is not my concern here. I'd like to modify the file direclty from within sublime editor.

Comment: This might not work with multiple levels. Perhaps you could expand it a little bit replacing multiple spaces at line start with appropriate no of tabs ( or bunch of 4 spaces ) ?

Comment: @Cqnqrd so what's this question have to do with Python?

Comment: @Gabriel because Sublime is written in Python and I guess a working Python solution would work within Sublime?

Comment: @rvraghav93, thanks, updated to deal with any number of white spaces

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want spaces, try this expression.
s/ /\t/g;
You could replace the space " " with some other regex character for more flexibility ("\s", for example).

In perl it could be..

$i =~ s/ /\t/g;
print "$i\n";

I just noticed the "python" tag. Sorry for the perl example and lack of one in python.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
code = """Level1 with some text
 Level2 
Level1 
  Level3 and its text"""

TAB = "\t" # You could also give TAB="    " ( 4 spaces )

# Spaces at line start are replaced with TAB
code = code.replace('\n ', '\n'+TAB)

while code.find(TAB+" ") is not -1 :
    # For multilevel indentation
    code = code.replace(TAB+' ', TAB*2)

print code
```

Output :

```
Level1 with some text
    Level2 
Level1 
        Level3 and its text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookbehind assertion:

```
text="""Level1 with some text
         Level2 
        Level1 
          Level3 and its text"""


re.sub(r'(?<=\s) ', r'\t', text, flags=re.M)
```

This replaces each space that is preceded by whitespace/newlines with a `\t`, so Level 3 will have two tabs, and Level 2 will only have one. The spaces between words will be unaffected. Output:

```
Level1 with some text
    Level2 
Level1 
        Level3 and its text
```